# Translating "X would be as if Y"

Tags: translation

A couple of times when arguing with someone on facebook (an important procrastination activity) I wanted to say something like "something happening would be as if something else happened", as in say "voting for candidate Fiulo would be as if you stuck a fork in your eye".  So basically I want to say some action or statement or whatnot would be like something else.  I came up with "... estus kiel ...", but it just didn't sound correct.  Is that correct?  What would be the alternatives?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think *kiel* or even *samkiel* would be correct in your example. However there is also the very nice word *kvazaŭ* which I think would work better. Eg,

> Voĉdoni por la kandidato Fiulo estus kvazaŭ piki sian propran okulon per forko.

Here is another example of the word being used in a similar way found via the [Tekstaro](http://tekstaro.com/):

> […] kavaliro sen amatino **estus kvazaŭ** arbo sen radiko […]

Answer (score 3):

Foje oni hezitas pri la diferenco inter "kiel" kaj "kvazaŭ". Eblas legi pri la diferenco en la [jena artikolo](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/komparoj/aliaj.html) de PMEG. Mallonge, oni uzas kvazaŭ por emfazi ke la komparo estas "nur ŝajna aŭ nereala", kiel vi priskribis.